# Dual booting windows 10 and fedora 30 issue with bootloader

Tags: fedora, dual-boot, uefi, boot-loader

While installing fedora on my pc there was a warning with "failed to set new efi boot target". After when i continued later when i start my pc it shows no bootable device -- inser boot disk.

What should i do now . I am new on linux os, so please help me out.

Comment: Is your Windows 10 installed in UEFI mode as well?

Comment: Yes Windows was installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: If so try first disabling the Windows Fast Startup feature as it can in some circumstances hold down the EFI partition as well.

Comment: How will i disable windows fast startup feature. As i can't enter into the windows.

Comment: So your problem is likely a corrupt drive, reason why Fedora failed to install Grub.

Comment: So is it that all my data in windows is also gone?

Comment: Questions about Windows are off-topic here (and the answer woul be "I don't know without more info"). If you're trying to use Fedora to somehow repair Windows that's a bad idea and it's silly. But if you want a duaboot as the title suggests then fix Windows first. You may need Windows media, of course, and if you need help with Windows please ask at superuser.com.